# The name userInput does not exist in the current context. Why?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this at the moment:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Which teams have played? right vs inbetween the two teams");
    Match m = Regex.Match("^(?<team1>\.+) vs (?<team2>\.+)$", userInput); 
    if (m.Success) 
    {     
        string team1 = m.Groups["team1"].Value;
        string team2 = m.Groups["team2"].Value; 
    } 

    Console.WriteLine("What is the score? ");    
    Match m = Regex.Match("^(?<score1>\.+)/(?<score2>\.+)$", userInput);
    if (m.Success) 
    {
        int score1 = m.Groups ["score1"].Value;
        int score2 = m.Groups ["score2"].Value;
    }
```

I get an error on the dot saying:

> "Unrecognized escape sequence `^(?<team1>\.+)`"

It also does tells me this on the `score1` and `score2` lines:

> "The type or namespace name  `Match` could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an essembly reference?)"

And:

> "The name `Regex´ does not excist in the current context."

What I am trying to do is to read two answers from one line and read it as two answers.

For example: BlueTeam vs RedTeam.

Also want to do the same thing for the score. For example: 1/1  I know the slash is a bit weird but I just did it out of pure laziness to think of something else.

And later on the path I want to assign this into a xy-table. Like so: http://pastebin.com/ahgP04bU

Comment: Use a @ before your regex strings:  `@"^(?<team1>\.+) vs ...$"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By putting your variables in `{ ... }`, you're creating a separate block scope with those variables.  They don't exist outside that scope.

Don't do that.

The `Regex` class is in the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace; you need to include that namespace using the `using` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You also have to include

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

in order to use regular expressions without fully qualifying.

Edit: There is a lot that would also improve your code. When you define your variables inside the `if` blocks, those variables are then locally scoped to the if block and are garbage collected as soon as the if block finishes.

Also, I don't see where userInput is defined anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to scope the namespace, the braces (`{ }`) are currently missing.
- You need `using System.Text.RegularExpressions` at the top of the file with the others.
- `userInput` doesn't exist, you need to declare it: `var userInput = string.Empty;`
- If strings have special characters in them (such as `\`), you can use `@`: `@"\myString"`

Comment: at ur third statement it says: var userInput = string.empty; string does not contain a definition for empty

Comment: @deltu: Apologies. A typo - `empty` should have been capitalised; I have updated.

Comment: @deltu: Though, you don't want to take that too literally: the string will need to have a meaningful value, the point it that it needs to be declared _and_ set.

Comment: Well the string needs to be the input really. I need to type that in. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Use something alone the lines of `var userInput = Console.ReadLine();`.